# Change the style of an element by the router path

Tags: angular, typescript

I've got a parent component which holds in the HTML a navigation-element and shows different components depending on which link is chosen, e.g.

```
<nav>
    <a routerLink="/hello">Hello</a>
    <a routerLink="/world">World</a>
</nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Now, I want to change the style of the navigation-link, that is chosen. So I declared a variable in the TypeScript file and initialized it with "hello", because that is the path that is loaded at the start of the Application:

```
selected: string = 'hello';
```

and a method:

```
setSelected(selected: string): void {
    this.selected = selected;
}
```

and changed the navigation to:

```
<nav>
     <a routerLink="/hello" [class.selected]="selected == 'hello'" 
         (click)="setSelected('hello');">Hello</a>
     <a routerLink="/world" [class.selected]="selected == 'world'"
         (click)="setSelected('wolrd');">World</a>
</nav>
```

In the CSS-sheet, I declarde the styles for the selected-class.

So far, this is working quite well, instead of one problem:
If I reload the page at the /world-path, the "Hello"-link is styled as selected, because the variable is initialized again, but the router-outlett still shows the content of /world.

**Is there a way, to change the style by using the current router-path, instead of the click-event or is there completely different way to solve this problem?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the build in directive called [**RouterLinkActive**](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive), which sets a css class based on the current active route.

Use it like this:

```
<nav>
  <a routerLink="/hello" routerLinkActive="selected">Hello</a>
  <a routerLink="/world" routerLinkActive="selected">World</a>
</nav>
```